# Domains of Utility Functions

Tags: utility-theory

I am learning a mathematical finance course and the lecturer didn't provide us with a rigorous definition of utility functions.

He just shows us (by simple Calculus) that the utility functions of every CRRA type agent are  $u(x)=\ln x$ or $\frac{x^{\gamma -1}}{\gamma -1}$, where $x$ is the wealth of the agent involved and $\gamma$ is the relative risk aversion constant.

He also shows that the utility functions of every CARA type agent is $u(x)=- \exp(-\alpha x)$, where $x$ is the wealth of the agent involved and $\alpha$ is the absolute risk aversion constant.

He didn't talk about the domains for both cases.

It is clear that the domain of $- \exp(-\alpha x)$ can be $\mathbb R$. However, if restricted in real analysis, the domains of $u(x)=\ln x$ and $\frac{x^{\gamma -1}}{\gamma -1}$ should be $\mathbb R^+$. This leads to my question that if different utility functions have different domains?

Remark: We can also define $u(x)=\ln x$ or $\frac{x^{\gamma -1}}{\gamma -1}$ on $\mathbb R^-$ by definition from complex analysis, but I guess this is not desired.

Comment: In finance, we usually consider utility functions over consumption which map the positive real line to $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @Kevin Hi Kevin, thanks for the comment. It helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As always, the answer depends a bit on the problem domain.

Commonly, utility functions only 'make sense' in terms of preference orderings, i.e.

$$B \succsim A \quad \Leftrightarrow \quad u(B)\geq u(A) \tag{1}\label{1}$$

If the agent weakly prefers $B$ over $A$, then their utility of $B$ must be weakly larger than that of $A$.

There are two types of utility functions, [cardinal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinal_utility) and [ordinal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_utility). Both map preferences to $\mathbb R$ (or some subdomain of it). The cardinal theory speaks of "utils" as a measurable / comparable quantity, whereas in the ordinal world (implicitly found in most of the quant finance world, IMO), only the ordering (i.e. rank) of consumption bundles / lotteries are relevant. Both worlds are compatible with \eqref{1}, of course.

All that *really matters* (in this discussion) is the monotonicity of the utility function or of any transformation of the utility function. **More is better**, independent of the domain of the utility function - as long as \eqref{1} is satisfied.

HTH?

Comment: Hi Kermittfrog, thanks for the post, which clarifies some notions of utility functions. Yes, later after I posted this question, I found the domain depended on the context.